# assigning value to label using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using JQuery 1.8.3. I have below HTML label.

```
<label for="myalue" style="vertical-align: middle"></label>
```

Now using JQuery i need to set a string to above label and am trying as below.

```
 $("label[for='myalue']").text("someText");
```

Above code works only in IE. But in Firefox label value is not set.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: It's working for me. Try with this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/per95/

Comment: Looks weird. However it works in all the browsers including Firefox.

Comment: He may be using older firefox version.

Comment: @user755806: Which Firefox version used by you?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

html:

```
<label for="myalue" style="vertical-align: middle"></label>
```

jquery code :

```
jQuery("label[for='myalue']").html("asd");
```

live example :

http://jsfiddle.net/GA7ur/1/

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to use

```
$("label[for='myalue']").html("someText");
```

or

```
$("label[for='myalue']").text("someText");
```

The only difference between html & text is that:

html() get/set HTML of an element

text() get/set innertext of an element

In you case I would use text() as it should be faster (at least looking at the jquery code). 
I've just tested both of this functions in chrome, IE9 and firefox and they work fine with label tag.

Comment: Why using `.html()` instead of `.text()`? Any specific reason or just a _try this_ answer? Why shouldn't `.text()` work?

Comment: The reason is that it does work... I'm looking at it now so hopefully I would be able the give you a better answer in few minutes

Comment: @BlackSheep there is no difference in this case and both of the functions work just fine. In fact text() should be faster so there is no reason to use html(). I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$().html('someText')` to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.html()`

Try this

```
$("label[for='myalue']").html("YourText");
```